# What's the simplest way to use VSTS Build with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, build, azure-devops

My code repository is all in Visual Studio Team Services and I already have a CI process with success building a core 2.0 application. The process restores packages, build, run tests and publish the artifact in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory). Everything is fine!

The problem is that I need to publish my app in AWS.
Is there a simple way, for example, the vsts catch the artifact in the output directory and deploy it in EC2 server using Web Deploy?

Most of the solutions that I saw used S3, Code Deploy and Lambda, solutions from AWS....Is It possible to use **JUST VSTS** to **build and deploy** for an AWS EC2 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) is an extension for Microsoft VSTS and on-premises Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) that makes it easy to deploy .NET applications to AWS. If you already use Microsoft VSTS or TFS, the AWS Tools for VSTS makes it easy to deploy your code to AWS without changing how you run your project, organize your builds, and track your work.

With the AWS Tools for VSTS, you can develop your .NET applications with the build/release system you already know, and deploy them directly to AWS EC2 instances using either AWS CodeDeploy or AWS Elastic Beanstalk. You can deploy a serverless .NET application to an AWS Lambda function. You can use your VSTS tools to deploy AWS CloudFormation templates, which gives you an easy way to manage, provision, and update a collection of AWS resources in a predictable fashion. You can also use the AWS Tools for VSTS to store your build artifacts in Amazon S3, run AWS CLI or PowerShell commands, and manage notifications through Amazon SNS or Amazon SQS queues.

[AWS Tools for Visual Studio Team Services](https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Different ways to do that is explained below.

How to Build a CI/CD Pipeline Using AWS CodeDeploy and Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS)
(For hybrid/complex deployments, you can use this. You can deploy IIS websites, MSI packages, services, exe). The beauty of this is that with a single deployment you can deploy to both on premises and cloud environment.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIE0P3m9eEY

How to Integrate AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) or (VSTS)
(for IIS websites/batch jobs you can use this)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRLZZefLDqU

How to Integrate AWS Cloudformation with Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS)
(fully infrastructure automation and manage infrastructure as code)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WU93NJT0_3s